# Pell's equation for n=2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

If know that $x=3$, $y=2$ is a solution of
$$x^2-2y^2=1,$$
then apparently all other solutions can be calculated as
$$x_k+y_k\sqrt{2}=(x+y\sqrt{2})^k,$$
which I have trouble understanding. I've been told that it can be seen thorugh the continued fraction of $\sqrt{2}$, but I don't see it. Could someone explain to me what exactly the idea is and how I prove this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much I want to explain, given how many times I have answered this question, but all solutions $(x,y)$ with non-negative entries can be found by beginning with $(1,0)$ and then finding the next pair with
$$ (3 x + 4 y, 2 x + 3 y).  $$
$$$$
$$ (1 ,0 ),  $$
$$ ( 3,2 ),  $$
$$ (17 ,12 ),  $$
$$ ( 99,70 ),  $$
$$ (577 ,408 ),  $$
$$ ( 3363,2378 ),  $$
$$ ( 19601,13860 ),  $$
$$ (114243 ,80782 ), \ldots  $$

It is also true that $(x_n, y_n)$ obey
$$ x_{n+2} = 6 x_{n+1} - x_n,  $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 6 y_{n+1} - y_n.  $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you briefly  explain where the continued fraction of $\sqrt{2}$ comes into play?