# Find all integer solutions to $x^2-2y^2=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

For the Pell's equation where $d=2$:
$$x^2-2y^2=1$$
What are all the integer solutions to the equation. Apparantly there are infinitely many solutions, but how would I represent them in an expression?

Comment: I don't believe there are infinitely many.  I believe there are $2$.  What have you attempted?

Comment: Maybe you can try using continued fractions. :)

Comment: @emka there are definitely more than $2$ (OP is correct in the statement that there are infinitely many). Here are a few: $(x,y) = (\pm 1,0)$, $(\pm 3, \pm 2)$, $(\pm 17, \pm 12)$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation#Fundamental_solution_via_continued_fractions) for an explanation of awllower's comment.

Comment: I'm caught up now.  I remembered this as an example from a number theory course (a few years ago).  The (x,y) pairs will be good approximations for $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: **Please** do not do that again. I will suspend you immediately if you do.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309613/general-solution-to-x2-2y2-1) for more answers. I gave a detailed answer there.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/931450/11619).

Answer (score 2):

Just note that for any pair $(a,b)$ giving a solution to $x^2-2y^2=1$, you have
$$(a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})=1.$$
That is, $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. The units
in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$  are well known, they are  powers  $\pm (1+\sqrt{2})^n$, with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. For instance,
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^4=17+12\sqrt{2}$$ 
gives you  a solution $(a,b)=(17,12)$.
For  more details, see e.g. here : [The units of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280878/the-units-of-mathbb-z-sqrt2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use continued fractions to find natural solutions. $\frac{x}{y} = [1;2,2,2,2,2,..... ] = \frac{p}{q}$ gives pairs (p,q) satisfying the Pell's equation.