# If $x$ and $y$ are integers satisfying $x^2 - 2y^2=1$, show that 6 is the greatest natural number always dividing $xy$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

**Problem**:

If $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfy $x^2-2y^2=1$, show that $6$ is the largest number always dividing $xy$

**My Attempt**:

I've been able to show that 6 indeed always divides $xy$, but not that it's the largest number to do so.

We have,
$$\begin{align*}
2y^2 &= x^2-1 \\
\implies 2y^2 &= (x-1)(x+1) \\
\implies 4&\mid 2y^2\\
\implies 2&\mid y \\
\implies 2&\mid xy
\end{align*}$$

Further, $y^2 \equiv_3 1 \implies x^2 \equiv_3 0$, hence, $3\mid xy$. Hence, $6 \mid xy$.

The general solution to the given Diophantine equation is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095694/find-all-integer-solutions-to-x2-2y2-1?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I don't see how that helps us here. Any help or hints are appreciated.

Comment: The classic way of doing this would be to find some small solutions for which $6$ was the largest number - clearly $6$ persists. In lucky cases there will be a solution with a product of $6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximality of $6$ follows because $3^2-2\cdot 2^2=1$ is a solution to the equation.